# How to stop Auth user from visiting own page with non auth user privileges in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes

My laravel application is a social media site. Here's the route for visiting another laravel user's profile

```
Route::get('/dashboard/{id}', [
'uses' => 'UserController@getProfile',
'as' => 'profile.index',
'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

It works just fine. However, I've discovered a bug that when I input the Auth user's ID into the route, I get taken to the same page where I can then add myself as a friend, I do not want this to happen. I would rather get taken back to the home screen if I'm visiting my own profile.

Here's the controller:

```
 public function getProfile($id)
{

    if(Auth::user() === $id)
        redirect('dashboard');

    $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();

    $posts = Post::where("dash_id", "=", $user->id)->latest()->paginate(3);
    $photos = Photo::paginate(6);
    return view('profile.index',compact('user','posts', 'photos'));

}
```

I've tried to get it to redirect to 'dashboard' instead of 'profile.index' if it's the Auth user's page instead of pulling up just like a regular non-auth profile, but can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas on how to fix this small bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get user instance by `Auth::user()` not only the user ID. You are comparing instance with the numeric value. It will not work. You have to use `Auth::id()` or `Auth::user()->id` in order to get ID of the logged in user. The following code will work in your case.

```
public function getProfile($id)
{

    if(Auth::id() == $id)
    {
        redirect('dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
        $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
        $posts = Post::where("dash_id", "=", $user->id)->latest()->paginate(3);
        $photos = Photo::paginate(6);
        return view('profile.index',compact('user','posts', 'photos'));
    }
}
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: It stopped pulling the Auth profile as a regular profile, but now instead of redirecting I simply get a blank page.

Comment: I got it now, just had to add return into the redirect :) thank you!

Comment: Yep!! This is the answer you need.

Answer (score 0):

You try to compare the current user object to the request id, try this code:

```
public function getProfile($id)
{
    if(Auth::id() === $id) {
        redirect('dashboard');
    }

    $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();

    $posts = Post::where("dash_id", "=", $user->id)->latest()->paginate(3);
    $photos = Photo::paginate(6)

    return view('profile.index',compact('user','posts', 'photos'));
}
```